# Entity Framework how to derive from a non existent class

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, ef-code-first

Please bear with me, I am not a developer, so I apologise if I don't use the correct terminology, but I am building a very simple stock management app using code first EF. I have one class which is my Products (simplified for brevity):

```
public class Product()
{
    this.Shops = new HashSet<Shop>
}
public int Id { get; set; }
public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Shop> Shops { get; set; }
```

And my Shop class:

```
public Shop() 
{
    this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
}
public int Id { get; set; }
public string ShopName { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Not all products will be available at all shops, and the above works perfectly.  EF has created the mapping table ProductShop and I can make whatever products I like available at any of the shops.

My problem is how to deal with the quantity of each item that is available at each shop.  Initially I thought I could just derive a new class from the ProductShop entity with a quantity field like this:

```
public class ShopStockQuantities : ProductShop
{
    public int Qty { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't have a physical class to derive from.  If I add that class, will EF get in a knot as that table already exists?  I am sure this issue has been encountered before, so to save me hours of experimenting (as I am not very good at this anyway) I thought I would seek advice from this Borg of experts.  Any advice gratefully received.

Comment: Inheriting from not existing classes is of course not possible. A correct solution here is to introduce this linking class in an explicit way: add it to your model and also, make one-many relationships between the newly introduced class and both of your existing classes (and of course, drop the existing many-many relation).

Comment: OK, a Shop has Products. But why does a Product have Shops?  That's a bit of double administration you can do without. `Product <- Stock(Qty) <- Product`.  When certain items are only allowed in certain shops then that is totally separate from stock keeping.

Comment: I take your point HH, and thanks for your input.  I now have the Product -> Stock Qty set up and working.  Just to confirm, are you saying I now need to map Stock Qty to product again (which is where I just got to with this, but looking for confirmation before I head off down that route)  Thanks also @Wiktor, you got me moving in the right direction.

Comment: With the code below a link (HashSet) from Product to Stock wouldn't be wrong. If it is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you've provided, this is one possible class structure which basically reflects what Wiktor and HH are saying.

```cs
public class Product
{
    [Key] public int ProductId { get; set; } 
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; } = "Not Set";
}

public class Shop
{
    [Key] public int ShopId { get; set; }
    public string ShopName { get; set; } = "Not Set";
    public ICollection<Stock> StockItems { get; set; } = new Collection<Stock>();
}

public class Stock
{
    [Key] public int StockId { get; set; }
    public int ShopId { get; set; }  // foreign key link to Shop
    public int ProductId { get; set; }   // foreign key to Product
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```